# Preparing Jekyll for GitHub Pages at the root of a personal site (isn't baseurl unnecessary?)

Tags: css, jekyll, github-pages

I am using the `github-pages` gem (version 195) to create a Jekyll site that will be hosted by GitHub Pages.

I've searched the documentation for GHPages and Jekyll for a few days, and there are so many outdated or irrelevant questions and answers that I have found no clear answer for this topic. Most questions pertain to hosting the site in a sub-directory of the root (ex. "example.com/mysite"), but I have had no luck finding questions about the root so my question *should* be a new one:

> How does one configure a Jekyll site through GitHub Pages *at the root of a personal domain* (ex. "example.com/")?

It *seems* like this should be very easy for direct HTML references, like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/styles.css"`, or pointing to local assets like image files `src="/assets/images/award.jpg"`. These files should to be hosted at `example.com/assets/css, images, etc.` They should not change on `jekyll serve` or production through GitHub Pages, so I should not require relative listing workarounds that are contained in [the Jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/) such as:

- `<link href="{{ "/assets/css/styles.css" | relative_url }}" rel="stylesheet">`
  or
- `[{{ page.title }}]("{{ page.url | relative_url }}")`

However, I have attempted to do this with my personal site, https://monjibram.com. When I attempt to implement this in reality, the CSS file (and ONLY the CSS file - not the other hosted assets like images) is unavailable. Further, I find that the CSS file *is* available and compiled at https://benjithaimmortal.github.io/monjibram/assets/css/style.css

A further question (if unanswered):

> Why did only the compiled CSS file land outside of my personal domain, while the rest of the assets were served properly?

I've attached the repo, in case there is something I forgot to add: https://github.com/benjithaimmortal/monjibram/

Comment: It's rather subtle but the link to your stylesheet has "styles.css" (plural) but above you have just "style.css". I would imagine you have a similar problem with "Teaching.JPG"

Comment: I agree, and I've tried different names for the CSS files. I think the compiler might create a new file for production. If there were an issue with the filename, it would break locally wouldn't it? I've got it fully functioning locally, but I'm only getting issues when I deploy. I would hate to bother everyone's time with a fat-finger...

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the typo that may have been confusing. In my source code, everything is styles (plural). But in production, the working link to CSS is singular (`style.css`). 

`Teaching.JPG` may be halting because it's wrapped in a link, while the other two pictures aren't. But unfortunately again, it works fine locally and it's the appropriate path.

Comment: On a hunch, and against https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/07-assets/, I relabeled everything `style.css`. Now it loads partial CSS, but can't handle the SASS.

Comment: Actually, there is no assets/css files.

Comment: I was overly excited until I found that my re-naming update had not pushed properly.  It's there now, and still broken. Also, because I'm compiling SCSS, I'm afraid the filenames will still differ (`style.css` and `style.scss`)

Comment: ... and now suddenly it works! But. Does that mean that Jekyll's step-by-step instructions are incorrect?